# PHP is_a() return false for array?

Tags: php

```
var_dump(is_a([], "array"));
```

The above code displays "false".

But,

```
echo gettype([]);
```

Displays "array".

Am I doing something wrong or missing out on something here?

Comment: Have you tried to check which arguments `is_a` consumes? Taken from the documentation: " Returns true if the **object** is of this **class** or has this class as one of its parents, false otherwise. " (emphasis added by me)

Comment: For the same reason it also yields "false" if you do `is_a(1, "integer")`. It's meant to use with objects or classes.

Comment: I think OP can be forgiven for the confusion, given that in many languages an array is considered a type of object (just not in PHP).

Comment: So basically an array does not extend the Iterator or Traversable class? I was finding a common word for describing the usage of foreach loop, like foreach loop can be used to iterate these type of object/values in PHP

Comment: @HenloWald In PHP, an array does not extend `Iterator` or `Traversable`.  `foreach` can work with `array`s or `object`s, ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @HenloWald I've added an answer to illustrate how to test if _something_ is iterable, which I think is what you are asking.

Comment: Yes @Martin, you're right. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the question and what has been described in the comments, it sounds like you're looking for a way to identify if *something* (i.e an array or object) is iterable.

In PHP, this can be achieved with `is_iterable()`, which will return `true` if the passed-in parameter supports iteration via `foreach`.

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php):

> Verify that the contents of a variable is accepted by the iterable
> pseudo-type, i.e. that it is either an array or an object implementing
> Traversable

In the case of the array you mentioned in the question:

```
is_iterable([]));
```

Outputs:

```
bool(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

`is_a()` function checks if the **object is of this class or has this class as one of its parents**

To check if something is an `array`, you should use `is_array()`.